# how to get data from api(Map type) for dropdown option

Tags: android, flutter

I have a problem when i want to get data from api and show them in dropdown option, I can print data when i run my code but in dropdown option i have below error :

type '(dynamic) => DropdownMenuItem' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry' of 'transform'

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:dropdownfield/dropdownfield.dart';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    import 'dart:async';`enter code here`
    import 'dart:convert';

       class InBoundRate extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _InBoundRateState createState() => _InBoundRateState();
    }

      class _InBoundRateState extends State<InBoundRate> {



     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
           return Scaffold(
         body: new Center(
            child: new FutureBuilder(
                future: GetInbound(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Map> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    Map content = snapshot.data ;
                    var sampleData = json.encode(content);
                var json2 = JsonDecoder().convert(sampleData);
//                    print(json2['data']['countries']);
                    return DropdownButton(

                      items: json2.map(
                        (item) => DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: item['data']['countries'],
                            child: Text(item['data']['countries'])),
//                          onChanged: (Users value) {
//                            setState(() {
//                              _currentUser = value;
//                           });
//                          }
                      ),
                      isExpanded: false,
                      //value: _currentUser,
                      hint: Text('Select User'),
                    );


                  } else {
                     return new Container();
                  }
                }),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    Future<Map> GetInbound() async {
      String apiUrl = 'http://homaexpressco.ir/api/getRatesInformation2';
      http.Response response = await http.get(apiUrl);
      var res = json.decode(response.body);
       return res;
    }
```

Comment: Does it work if you chain `.toList()` after the `.map()`?

Comment: I add .toList() but still have error  => Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'map' with matching arguments.
Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:2
Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>, onChanged: Closure: (dynamic) => Null)
Found: map<K2, V2>((K, V) => MapEntry<K2, V2>) => Map<K2, V2>